# 10413-The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: paypal, magento2

From the magento admin whenever I try to make the payment with zero subtotal and shipping charges  then it shows this error:

Field format error: 10413-The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

I need the solution to fix this.

Comment: which payment method did you try? Paypal Express? and single product or multiple products with sub total is zero?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not process payments for zero amounts. You need to activate a zero amount payment method if you wish to be able to process such "transactions".

If the total amount is *not* zero, then the error indicates the various subamounts and amounts of items specified do not add up to the total correctly, which PayPal also cannot process.